# How to get issues assigned to root in YouTrack

Tags: youtrack

```
{Assigned to root by Priority} project: xyz-anonym
```

i dont want write:

```
{Assigned to me by Priority} project: xyz-anonym
```

because i want to use it as link for other members

[Link to youtrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/%20http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a saved search like this: `Assignee: root order by: Priority project xyz-anonym` and share it.